# Angular Check location from index page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to hide navBar if i'm on some locations. A have the index page:

```
<navbar ng-show="showNavbar"></navbar>
<div ng-view></div>
```

with js:

```
scope.showNavbar=(window.location.hash == '#/login');
```

I tried to put a location checker to the mainCtrl, but than, it wasn't check the location just once. 
After that, i put into my goClick directive

```
.directive( 'goClick', function ( $location) {
        return function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            var path;

            attrs.$observe( 'goClick', function (val) {
                path = val;
            });

            scope.showNavbar=(window.location.hash == '#/login');


            element.bind( 'click', function () {
                scope.$apply( function () {
                    $location.path( path );
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

it checked it, but couldn't pass the value neither the html page nor the Ctrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<navbar ng-show="showNavbar"></navbar>
```

to

```
<navbar ng-show="showNavbar()"></navbar>
```

and controller

```
scope.showNavbar = function(){
   if($location.path() =='/login'){
    return true; 
   }else{
     return false; 
    }
}
```